# How to color all the rows based on the cell values

Tags: excel, vba

Its quite different than the other requests. Could you please help me to color the rows(just light colors) based on the values. for eg,

```
ColA   ColB
Add    1234
Add    1234
Add    1234
Del    1234
Del    5678
Del    5678
Chg    1235
Chg    1235
Chg    1235
```

here, using the macro it needs to color the rows when the values are changing in `colB` like `1234` to `5678` or anything.

Please help me on this...

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, Groves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use conditional formatting. https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67